# Android Random Reboots - Clearing /proc/last_kmsg

Tags: android, debugging, kernel

We are trying to diagnose random reboots on our Nexus 7 tablets. Reboots look like: Application is non-responsive, black screen, cyanogenmod splash screen, normal lock screen, tablets function normally. One theory is kernel panics. I've yet to get my hands on a device after a crash (they are in the field) but I can cause a kernel panic that produces the same crash as described by the testers. The resulting /proc/last_kmsg shows this:

```
[ 2431.183227] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
[ 2431.183502] wcnss_8960: crash shutdown : 0
[ 2434.686065] Rebooting in 5 seconds..
[ 2439.688842] Going down for restart now
[ 2439.689239] in panic

No errors detected
Boot info:
Last boot reason: Panic
```

For testing I wrote a little program that tests for the existence of /proc/last_kmsg. If it is there, I use cat /proc/last_kmsg > file_path to get a copy of the file.  I'd like to remove, clear, rename the /proc/last_kmsg file so I don't keep getting files copied over. It seems like once the last_kmsg file is there, it is there forever. Is there a way to get rid of this file?

Any thoughts about debugging random crashes? I already have ACRA running when my program is running and I've never seen a bug report when a sudden crash is reported by a user.

Thanks

Should note we're running on the new Nexus 7 with cyanogenmod.

Comment: I did find that powering off the tablet does remove the last_kmsg. I'm hoping there is another way.

Comment: If you only examine it as the device is booting, you shouldn't see the same file twice (since it changes on every reboot).  After a normal reboot you'll see "Last boot reason: reboot" as the last line, so you can ignore those.  It's a /proc entry, not a regular file, so there's not a whole lot you can do to it.  You could assume that the file size won't be the same on adjacent reboots and just keep track of the size of the file the last time you looked at it -- ignore last_kmsg if the current size matches the previous size.  Would be safer to md5sum the contents.

Comment: @fadden Thanks for the md5sum suggestion. That should help my internal bug reporting and tracking. I don't the file sent each time my program starts, which is where I checking for the file.